# Import Error, When I import nltk.corpus.framenet in NLTK Python

Tags: python, nltk

I have to use framenet in nltk.corpus. So, I downloaded that corpus by using the nltk.download(). And the framenet directory is now C:\nltk_data\corpora\framenet_v15...

But when I import that framenet, I can't. I can't find the reason.
I want to some works as explained in here; http://nltk.org/howto/framenet.html

```
>>> import nltk.corpus.framenet

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk.corpus.framenet
ImportError: No module named framenet
```

Please, help me. Thanks.

Comment: I think framenet comes on nltk v3 and higher, I might be wrong though, what nltk version do you have ?

Comment: My nltk version is '2.0.4'... Maybe you're right. I will try it right away..

Comment: See this: http://nltk.org/install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your link it import as so:

```
from nltk.corpus import framenet
```

Have you tried that?

EDIT: Version 3.0 and above of NLTK has framenet in the `nltk.corpus.reader` package, so it should be:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import framenet
```

Comment: Sure, I did. This is what I got.                                                     >>> from nltk.corpus import framenet

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import framenet
ImportError: cannot import name framenet

Comment: Unfortunately... I got the same error. >>> from nltk.corpus.reader import framenet

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader import framenet
ImportError: cannot import name framenet

Comment: What version do you have? The newest version of NLTK has framenet in the nltk.corpus.reader package: http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#module-nltk.corpus.reader.framenet

Comment: Thanks. The problem was the version of nltk. It was 2.0.4 version.. Thanks again!